# Scope is not being added to Access Token returned from Azure Ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

**Overview**

We have an Azure AD secured API living in Azure as a web app. We need to be able to:

1. Trigger this API via user interaction from a client application (this part works).
2. Trigger this API programmatically from a scheduled job that will simply get a token & hit this API (this part does not work due to authentication issues).

**Problem**

The issue is that when we request a token from Azure AD, scope is not being set in our token claims resulting in the API rejecting the token.

This is the request we are making:
[image]

This request returns an access token with the following claims:

```
{
  "aud": "<our api client id>",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0",
  "iat": 1644421512,
  "nbf": 1644421512,
  "exp": 1644425412,
  "aio": "<value>",
  "azp": "<scheduled job client id>",
  "azpacr": "1",
  "oid": "<guid>",
  "rh": "<value>",
  "sub": "<guid>",
  "tid": "<guid>",
  "uti": "<value>",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

As you can see `scp` (scope) is not included in the token claims even though we include it in the request.

If we use this token to make a request to our API we get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.
```

Any help on how we can get an access token from Azure AD with the proper scope/permissions to call our API, would be greatly appreciated.

**Note**

The Azure AD App Registration for our scheduled job that will request a token and then hit our API, does have the Delegated API Permission `access_as_user` which you can see I am including in the token request's scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***The above is expected as using client credentials you can't get the delegated permissions i.e. the `access_as_user` permission and also the scope in client credentials should be used as `api://<APP_ID>/.default` . So , If you want delegated permissions then you will have to use implicit grant flow instead of client credentials.***

**For testing , I created two app registrations , One on which API is exposed (Postman) and other which is to be used for authentication (Powershelltest) and then , I have tested the same in 2 different scenarios like one for client credentials and another for implicit grant :**

**Main APP whose API has been exposed :**

[image]
[image]

**App used for authentication:**

[image]

[image]

**Scenario 1 Using Client Credential flow :**

[image]

[image]

**Scenario 2 using Implicit Grant flow :**

[image]

[image]